# get list of files in a folder BUT in a predetermined order

Tags: bash

I am using the below code to extract the names of files in a folder and then performing an operation on those files.

```
for library in lib/*
 do
  echo ${library##*/}
  cp -v ${library##*/} /opt/java/deploy/
 done
}
```

The above yields an output of :

```
camel-amqp-2.16.0.jar
netty-all.jar
proton-j.jar
qpid-jms-client.jar
```

I then need to copy the jar files one by one in the application deployment folder.

Right now I have 4 jar files but in the future the # of files will increase.

The above works all fine. But the dilemma for me is that I have to make sure that `qpid-jms-client.jar` & `camel-amqp-2.16.0.jar` are the last to load.

Basically I need to sort the output so that the qpid & camel jar files are at the bottom of the list and are hence the last ones to be loaded.

Using `sort` does not help here since sorting alphabetically wont be of much use.

Is there something else I can try out ?

Comment: Add two lines after the loop to copy those two and put an `if` statement inside the loop to ignore them there.

Comment: Alternatively, iterate through the output of `find lib/ -not -name aaa -and -not -name bbb` and then copy the remaining two files manually at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `extglob` you can do this:

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob

for lib in !(@(qpid-jms-client|camel-amqp-*)).jar qpid-jms-client.jar camel-amqp-*.jar; do

  echo "${lib##*/}"
  cp -v "${lib##*/}" /opt/java/deploy/

done
```

**How it works:**

- extglob pattern `!(@(qpid-jms-client|camel-amqp-*)).jar` matches all `*.jar` files except `qpid-jms-client.jar` & `camel-amqp-2.16.0.jar` files.
- Those 2 files are listed in the end to make sure these 2 jar files are always matched in the end